# sending user credentials with every HTTP requests in web api basic authentication while i take them once

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working on a REST mobile application using ASP.Net Web APIs, I took the user credential (username and password) once but I need to send them with every HTTP request, how can I keep the credential to send them with every HTTP request. These requests are sent to a SharePoint on-premise website.

Comment: Are you building the frontend, backend, or both? And why do you need to send the username and password with every HTTP request?

Comment: @dybzon I'm building the backend, how to get access to the website without credentials?

Comment: See Hassan's answer. I was going to suggest something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could think about JWT. sending username and password in every http request is not a secure way. In JWT way, you send user and password once and get a token and save it for example in browser local storage. Then for every request you send this token in header. for more information:

1- [JWT in Asp core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/#:%7E:text=JWT%20in%20ASP.NET%20Core&text=in%20web%20development.-,It%20is%20an%20open%20standard%20which%20allows%20transmitting%20data%20between,be%20easily%20verified%20and%20trusted.)

2 - [JWT in Java spring](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world)

3- [JWT in Php](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-authorization-jwt-json-web-tokens/)

Comment: I am sending requests to a Sharepoint website so depending on my understanding I need to send the credentials

Comment: Based on Share point documentation, it accept headr with name Authorization

Comment: Thank you i will try what you suggest